# Using Google+ SDK in iOS apps

Tags: ios, google-plus

Google plus SDK has been integrated in one of my apps for sharing the app content.

For this user has to login into Google plus account on the app and then use this sharing feature.

But, in the Google developer site it says that Google Plus login is deprecated and we need to implement Google login instead of Google Plus login.

I am not using Google Plus just for a login functionality.

So, what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in sharing you should probably be [using the SFSafariViewController to present the share dialog box in a webview](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share):

```
- (void)showGooglePlusShare:(NSURL*)shareURL {

  // Construct the Google+ share URL
  NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]
      initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];
  urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
      initWithName:@"url"
             value:[shareURL absoluteString]]];
  NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];

  if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
    // Open the URL in SFSafariViewController (iOS 9+)
    SFSafariViewController* controller = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]
        initWithURL:url];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
  } else {
    // Open the URL in the device's browser
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a GoogleSignIn SDK: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating.